# What image pre-processing steps can I take to make this image ocr-readable?

Tags: image-processing, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

[image: concerned image]

I am using tesseract ocr to extract text from this. While it is able to extract some information out of other similar images notwithstanding minor typos, it isn't able to detect a single word from this image. It has been binarized and gaussian blur applied to it. What other steps can I take to make it more ocr-friendly? thanks in advance :)

Comment: preprocessing cannot do anything. your image has insufficient resolution. I see these options: give up, get better resolution, deploy AI for OCR that is trained on this data.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR; try `--psm 4` - if that doesn't work, switch to PaddleOCR

When using Tesseract to do OCR on something that's not a scanned document (with a big block of consistently formatted text), you'll want to look for  the Page Segmentation Mode that best fits the format of your text.    The modes are optimized for different kinds of input, so Tesseract will produce dramatically superior/inferior results just because the right/wrong PSM is being used.

A function like this, for example, will let you try different PSMs and also test the effect of some basic image pre-processing.

```
from PIL import Image as pillowImageLoader
import pytesseract
import cv2
import numpy as np

def testTesseract(someFilename, psmValue=3, processABit=True):
    if processABit:
        img = np.array(pillowImageLoader.open(someFilename))
        norm_img = np.zeros((img.shape[0], img.shape[1]))
        img = cv2.normalize(img, norm_img, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
        img = cv2.threshold(img, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
        img = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (1, 1), 0)
    try:
        someText = pytesseract.image_to_string(someFilename, config='--psm {}'.format(psmValue))
        return someText
    except:
        return None
```

Then run through each psm and check your output:

```
for i in range(1,14):
    someText = testTesseract(imageFilename, i, processABit=True)
    print("PSM: {}".format(i))
    print(someText
    print("="*40)
```

If you can't get any kind of acceptable result with Tesseract, then something like PaddleOCR will typically be able to get your a result:

```
from paddleocr import PaddleOCR
ocr = PaddleOCR(use_angle_cls=True, lang='en',use_gpu=False)
result = ocr.ocr(imageFilename, cls=True)
print("Paddle Found: {} text segments".format(len(result[0])))
print()
for t in result[0]:
        print("{}  (Conf: {:.1%})".format(t[1][0], t[1][1]))
```

PaddleOCR uses techniques similar to, for example, facial recognition, where you can find faces anywhere in an image at any angle.   PaddleOCR will find all occurrences of text - any size, any orientation.

The one caveat here is that you often have to reassemble the text 'objects' yourself into something coherent, as Paddle doesn't necessarily determine the relationship of text 'objects' to each other.  A headline, for example, may be detected as one thing, and a body of text beneath it as another.   However, it's straightforward to use pixel locations to do the assembly if your text has a predictable layout.